# Optimising assigments of individuals to groups (with defined maximum capacity) according to individuals' preferences

Tags: r, loops, random, grouping, assign

I am attempting to populate a set of forests with individuals from various species. Each forest has a defined capacity which it cannot exceed (given by Forest Area * Organism Density). Each species has a set population size, which is a fraction of the total population, itself determined by the sum of all forest areas * organism density.

The species also have defined preferences in regards to which forests they are assigned to, according to a relationship with a characteristic that varies between the forests, say rainfall. This results in a matrix of probabilities of a given species individual being assigned to a given forest. In order to give an equal chance for each species to be allocated to its preferred forest, I am assigning one individual at a time, repeatedly iterating through all the species in order, until both the non-assigned species populations have been exhausted and all the forests are at their maximum capacity.

Ideally the proportion of a species' population in a forest will be as close as possible to the probability of that species being assigned to that forest. This will involve a compromise between all species to minimise the total error between the population proportions and the species specific probabilities of assignment. (Thanks to commenters for making this a clearer problem)

At the moment I am doing this with a for, if/else, while loop. Here, when a patch reaches its capacity it is removed from the selection process, and when a species' population has all been assigned, it is iterated over. The species population sizes are stored in one data.frame and the forest capacities are stored in another, and are adjusted accordingly when individuals are assigned.

These criteria have led me to struggle to see an alternative method than the loops (reproducible example below). However, it is very slow as I often have total population sizes in the 100s of millions. I feel there must be a much neater and faster alternative to using loops, perhaps residing in the way I have structured the input data or in the way I provide equal oppurtunity to each species (i.e. a way this doesn't have to be sequential), but I cannot figure one out. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
set.seed(999)

#Generate data
nSpecies <- 50 #Number of species
max_area <- 10000 #Maximum Area of a forest
nForests <- 20 #Number of different forests
areas <- round(rbeta(nForests, 1, 2) * max_area) #Generate random forest areas

total_area <- sum(areas) #Find total area of all forests
density <- 10 #Set organism density
total_population <- total_area * density #Find total population size across all forests

pop_structure <- table(sample(1:nSpecies, total_population, replace = T)) #Generate species populations

forests <- data.frame(Name = 1:nForests,
                      Capacity = (areas * density), #Find max population size of each forest
                      Rainfall = sample(0:10000, nForests, replace = T)) #Generate forest characteristic variable (e.g. rainfall)

species <- data.frame(Species = 1:nSpecies,
                      Individuals = as.numeric(pop_structure), 
                      Rain_Response = rnorm(nSpecies, 0, 2)) #Generate species rainfall response


#Generate probabilities of assignment to each forest for each species
assignment_probs <- matrix(NA, nrow = nSpecies, ncol = nForests)

for(i in 1:nSpecies){
  for(x in 1:nForests){
    #Probability of assignment to forest = Exponent of species rain response * log(Rainfall in Forest)
    assignment_probs[i,x] <- exp(species$Rain_Response[i] * log(forests$Rainfall[x])) 
  }
  #Scale to sum to 1
  assignment_probs[i,] <- (assignment_probs[i,] / sum(assignment_probs[i,])) 
}

#Allocate species individuals to a forest
forest_comms <- matrix(0, nrow = nForests, ncol = nSpecies) #Empty community matrix

possible_forests <- 1:nForests #Vector to remove forests from selection without effecting other data
done <-  FALSE #Used to exit loop when finished

while(sum(species$Individuals) > 0){ #While individuals in the species pool remain to be assigned...

    for(sp in 1:nSpecies){ #Repeatedly assign one individual from each species until all done

      if(species$Individuals[sp] > 0){ #If species individuals remain to be assigned, proceed. Else, skip
        vacancies <- 0 #Set vacancies to 0 to enter next loop

        while(vacancies == 0){ #If there are 0 vacancies in forest selected in next section, retry assignment
          forest <- sample(possible_forests, 1, prob = assignment_probs[sp, possible_forests]) #Randomly select forest according to generated assignment probabilities
          vacancies <- species$Individuals[forest] #Find no. of individual vacancies yet to be filled in the forest

          if(vacancies > 0){ #If vacancies available in forest...
            forest_comms[forest, sp] <- (forest_comms[forest, sp] + 1) #Assign an individual to the forest
            species$Individuals[sp] <- (species$Individuals[sp] - 1) #Decrease species count by 1
            forests$Individuals[forest] <- (forests$Individuals[forest] - 1) #Decrease remaining vacancies in forest by 1

          } else { #If forest is already full...
            possible_forests <- possible_forests[!possible_forests %in% forest] #Remove forest from selection process 
          }

          if(length(possible_forests) == 1){ #If only one forest has vacancies...
            for(i in 1:nrow(species)){ #Assign all remaining individuals to that forest
              forest_comms[possible_forests, i] <- (forest_comms[possible_forests, i] + species$Individuals[i])
            }

            species$Individuals <- 0 #Set population to 0 (all individuals have been assigned)
            done <- TRUE #Convert 'done' to true to end loop
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }

  cat('\n', sum(species$Individuals))
  if(done){break}
} 

sum(forest_comms) == total_population
```

Comment: This sounds like a variation of what is sometimes called the "knapsack" problem, which could be solved in an optimized way using the `adagio` package.

Comment: This does sound similar, thanks for the suggestion. I'll look further into it, but the issue I see is that there isn't a optimal solution, the resultant matrix is desirably somewhat random (within the realms of the species preferences) and the preference is on the end of the species (object) rather than the forest (knapsack, or perhaps knapsack wearer). Edit: actually there is an optimal solution I suppose, having the largest number of individuals in their preferred forests, perhaps this is a better solution than what I was thinking

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?   Is it to generate a 20x50 non-negative matrix `forest_comms` such that `colSums(forest_comms) <= species$Individuals` and `rowSums(forest_comms) <= areas * density` and 
`prop.table(forest_comms, 2)` is closest in some sense to `t(assignment_probs)` ?

Comment: Yes. My intention was for it to be somewhat random, but yours and the above answers have made me realise there is a feasible optimal solution, i.e. as you say the proportions of the species populations are as close as possible to the assignment probs